# Python3 regex string formatting

Tags: python, regex, string, python-3.x, search

I try get formatting string using python3 regex - re

My input:

```
{'factorial.2.0.0.zip', 'Microsoft ASP.NET Web API 2.2 Client Libraries 5.2.3.zip', 'Newtonsoft.Json.9.0.1.zip'}
```

I try get only name and only version for packages, like that:

- factorial.2.0.0.zip

  - factorial
  - 2.0.0
- Microsoft ASP.NET Web API 2.2 Client Libraries 5.2.3.zip

  - Microsoft ASP.NET Web API 2.2 Client Libraries
  - 5.2.3

etc.
This my code

```
if diff is not None:
    for values in diff.values():
        for value in values:
            temp = ''
            temp1 = ''
            temp = re.findall('[aA-zZ]+[0-9]*', value) #name pack
            temp1 = re.findall('\d+', value) #version
            print(temp)
            print(temp1)
```

My wrong output:

```
 temp:
 ['Microsoft', 'ASP', 'NET', 'Web', 'API', 'Client', 'Libraries', 'zip']
 ['Newtonsoft', 'Json', 'zip']
 ['factorial', 'zip']

temp1:
['2', '0', '0']
['2', '2', '5', '2', '3']
['9', '0', '1']
```

Right output:

```
temp:
['Microsoft', 'ASP', 'NET', 'Web', 'API', 'Client', 'Libraries']
['Newtonsoft', 'Json']
['factorial']

temp1:
['2', '0', '0']
['5', '2', '3']
['9', '0', '1']
```

how me fix problem, delete "zip" is search and extra numbers. Maybe have another way solved my problem.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend to get rid of meaningless identifiers such as temp, whatever you change else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
import re

a = {'factorial.2.0.0.zip', 'Newtonsoft.Json.9.0.1.zip',\
     'Microsoft ASP.NET Web API 2.2 Client Libraries 5.2.3.zip',\
     'namepack010.0.0.153.212583'}

for b in a:
    c = re.findall('(.*?).(\d+\.\d+\.\d+)(\.zip|\.\d+)$', b)[0]
    if c[2] == '.zip':
        print c[0],'||',c[1]
    else:
        print c[0],'||',c[1]+c[2]
```

Output:

```
Newtonsoft.Json || 9.0.1
namepack010 || 0.0.153.212583
Microsoft ASP.NET Web API 2.2 Client Libraries || 5.2.3
factorial || 2.0.0
```

Don't use `[aA-zZ]` for selecting all alphabets. It will match some of the special characters also. You should use `[a-zA-Z]`

Check this for more understanding: [Why is this regex allowing a caret?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771901/why-is-this-regex-allowing-a-caret)

Comment: thanks man, you realy help, but I find name packgs 
which is not suitable this regex. He looks like this: `namepack010.0.0.153.212583` your regex return `('namepack010.0.0.153.', '12583')` maybe you can help me again?
right return this packs: `('namepack010' , '0.0.153.212583')`

Comment: my solution: `print(re.findall('(.*?\d*\s*)\.*(\d*[^a-zA-Z]*).zip', b)[0])`

Comment: @teror4uks Modified. Check now.